# Where is the .github folder in the project repository?

Tags: github

I want to add a few config files to `.github` folder but I can't seem to find it in my repository. I do see the `.git` and `.gitignore` files. Where can I find this `.github` folder, Is it added by git or should I create it?

Comment: Where is it in _what_ repository? If you can't see it, maybe it doesn't have one. Maybe you need to _create_ it, which is just basic computer use.

Comment: @jonrsharpe dot files are hidden and I just wanted to make sure it is really not there before I create one.

Comment: You say you _can_ see `.git` and `.gitignore`, which you wouldn't if you couldn't see dotfiles. We can't tell you whether or not a given directory is on your local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one unless you create it (and if you do, you should create it in the root directory for the repository).

Comment: i didn't have a .github folder and yml file inside the workflows folder. I had to create one and make a push. Before that i couldn't edit the yml file remotely even. Hope that helps someone